# SQL error 1064 fail to create a table

Tags: mysql, sql, key, create-table

Here is the exact code

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    ID int(11),
    name varchar(45),
    lname varchar(45),
    birth date,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
CREATE TABLE schools
(
    ID int(11),
    name varchar(35),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
CREATE TABLE courses
(
    ID char(7),
    name varchar(45),
    credits tinyint(4),
    school int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (school) REFERENCES schools(ID)
):
CREATE TABLE enrollment
(
    ID int(11),
    edate date,
    estart date,
    course char(7),
    studentid int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (studentid) REFERENCES students(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES courses(ID)
);
```

It runs through students and schools without problem, but when it gets to the courses table it stops with

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ': CREATE TABLE enrollment (
>       ID int(11),
>       edate date,
>       estart date,
>       cours' at line 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the colon `':'` into a semi-colon `';'`

Comment: Thank you! what a terribly noobish mistake :)

Comment: No problem: the rule of thumb is simply to carefully read what the error message tells you: most of the time it never lies to you and is helpful

Comment: I do read error messages and in fact love them for their ability of telling me what's wrong. But in SQL i usually just don't understand the errors, it's as if i do't know how to read them. For example it says line 9, but means line 15-23